# Minimum Spanning Tree Which Edges are Required/Unnecessary

Tags: tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

In a graph, for every edge, how do you determine whether or not it is in all minimum spanning trees, or just some of them, or none of them?

Assume there are < 1000 vertices and < 100000 edges, and we need to classify all edges.

Comment: This question smells like HW. We don't do HW for other people. Good luck!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". A handy reference is the Stack Overflow question checklist: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist. Then learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Finally, edit your question appropriately if you would like some help.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following to determine whether an edge appears in any of the MSTs or not. Let's say we have an undirected graph, we can determine if an edge appears in all Minimum Spanning Tree (MST). For every edge, do the following: let u and v be the two vertices of edge e. Run a standard DFS from u along edges that are not heavier than e to see whether we can reach v. If we can reach v, then some MST does not contain e. If we cannot reach v, then every MST contains e. This is because an edge appears in all MSTs if and only if the edge is not the heaviest edge in any cycle.